# Photoshop Scripting: How to make page numbers

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

Hello I was wondering if anyone can help me write a Photoshop script that will display a number and save the document incrementally?

I got to here so far:

```
if(app.documents.length != 0){  
    var doc = app.activeDocument;  
    for(i = 0; i < doc.artLayers.length; ++i){  
        var layer = doc.artLayers[i];  
        if(layer.kind == LayerKind.TEXT){  
            layer.textItem.contents = 1;  
            layer.textItem.size = 20;
        }  
    }  
}
```

But I'm having trouble writing the content with increments. I want it so that the page number on my document increases by 1.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't entirely clear what you are after.  This will increment the number shown, but every text layer it encounters will get numbered.

```
if(app.documents.length != 0){  
    var doc = app.activeDocument;  
    var j = 1;
    for(i = 0; i < doc.artLayers.length; ++i){  
        var layer = doc.artLayers[i];  
        if(layer.kind == LayerKind.TEXT){  
            layer.textItem.contents = j;  
            layer.textItem.size = 20;
            j++;
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks this actually works for me because I only have one text layer. However, I think I made a mistake in my for loop by setting the limit with artLayers.length. Supposedly, if I needed to make a number from 1 to 50, is there any way I can set the loop limit to 50?

Comment: looping through 50 art layers?? you'd just use: for(i = 0; i < 50; i++)